# Short and small FIVE letter word

Tags: riddle, word

> I am a five letter word, find
>   a part of me when digging around.
>   
>   Remove the first and last letters
>   to become a First Person Shooter.
>   
>   Remove the first two letters, and
>   I will handle versioning for better.
>   
>   What am I?

Note: No partial answers please.

Comment: Perhaps PC-Games tag can be added, if available !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably,

> Digit

a part of me when digging around.

> Dig it

Remove the first and last letters,
to become a First Person Shooter

> IGI

Remove the first two letters, and
I will handle versioning for better.

> git